# How to convert headerless ima-adpcm raw file to wav using sox

Tags: audio, wav, pcm, sox, adpcm

I am trying to convert a raw file (header-less) to wav

It is in ADPCM 16 rate 8000

I have tried three console commands

```
sox -e ima-adpcm -r 8000 input.raw output.wav
sox -e ima-adpcm -r 8000 -b 16 input.raw output.wav
```

These trigger the same error:

```
sox FAIL formats: bad input format for file `input.raw': data encoding or sample size was not specified
```

and last attempt

```
sox -t raw -t wav -e ima-adpcm -r 8000 -b 16 input.raw output.wav
```

which triggers another error

```
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `input.raw': WAVE: RIFF header not found
```

Do you know why I get these errors?

Thanks

EDIT

An hex dump of the first 48 bytes FYI

```
C0 0C 00 03 00 00 37 C0 34 0C D0 30 37 C0 30 C7 CD D3 C0 03 CD 00 37 03
C0 00 0D 0C CD 00 C0 10 0F 00 03 55 0B 4B 0F 0F 0C 0F 34 0F 0D C3 0D 03
00 C0 31 00 00 D0 C0 00 F4 4C 03 33 34 33 31 33 0D 33 D0 03 C0 4C C0 43
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like using `-t raw -e ima-adpcm` doesn't work, but rather you have to use `-t ima -e ima-adpcm`.

I guess `-t raw` means raw PCM, whereas `-t ima` means raw ADPCM?

This worked for me to convert an ADPCM file into .wav:

```
sox -t ima -r 44100 -e ima-adpcm in.raw -e signed-integer -b 16 out.wav
```

The file extension doesn't seem to matter as long as you indicate ADPCM with `-t ima`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the filename from `input.raw` to `input.ima` ? If you can, then

```
 sox input.ima -r 8000 -b 16 output.wav
```

ought to work. `.raw` seems to be a magic extension for `sox` and it assumes certain possibilities for the data. See [this man page](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxformat.html).

Comment: `sox WARN raw: input.ima: sample rate not specified; trying 8kHz`      
`sox WARN adpcms: input.ima: ADPCM state errors: 286079`

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino I've never done anything with an `.ima` file so flying blind here. Maybe just try `sox input.ima output.wav` and let SoX pick the params itself?